# Trying to write the code for the iforest algorithm in python

Tags: python, outliers, isolation-forest

I am trying to find outliers in a couple of different datasets from the UCI repository (thyroid, diabetes, and lymphography) currently I am working on the code for the iforest algorithm and i cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong? and what can I do to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\There\\Desktop\\thyroid-disease.csv')

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data\['sex'\] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data\['sex'\])
data\['on_thyroxine'\] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data\['on_thyroxine'\])
data\['query_on_thyroxine'\] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data\['query_on_thyroxine'\])
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data = data.astype(float)
selected_features = \['age', 'TSH'\]
X = data\[selected_features\]
clf = IsolationForest(contamination=0.1, random_state=42)
outliers = clf.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(X.iloc\[:, 0\], X.iloc\[:, 1\], color='k', s=3., label='Data points')
plt.scatter(X.iloc\[outliers == -1, 0\], X.iloc\[outliers == -1, 1\], color='r', s=30., label='Outliers')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title('Isolation Forest Outlier Detection')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('TSH')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does the code do differently than what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    data = data.astype(float)
   line 6534, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  line 414, in astype
    return self.apply(
   line 354, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
 line 616, in astype
    new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)line 238, in astype_array_safe
  line 183, in astype_arrayvalues = _astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  line 134, in _astype_nansafe
return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '?'

Comment: having at least a partial CSV so we can run the test would be helpful, but from the error messages I presume you're trying to convert non-numeric strings (here a question mark) into floating point numbers which is impossible for python to do

Comment: well yes there are some values in the dataset which are missing and filled with "?"